# Do modern compilers optimize local variables that just refer to subset of objects?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization

Do most modern compilers end up optimizing the following code so that extra instructions aren't used for the object `inner`?

```
func Test(TypeObject *object):
  InnerTypedObject *inner = object->inner
  print(inner->a)
  print(inner->b)
  print(inner->c)
```

I figured that compilers would be able to figure out that `inner->a` and `object->inner.a` refer to the same thing, so it would avoid allocating `inner` altogether. I figured the local variable is probably saved on a register, so I'm not really concerned about performance. Mainly wanted to know if we'd get the same generated machine code.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)? You can submit your code (be warned that it does go over the internet) and see the assembly that the compiler spits out. In that way, you can see exactly whether the compiler optimizes it away

Comment: Updated to indicate that there's types involved.

Comment: Where does `other` come from?

Comment: @It'scominghome Note that this is not a debugging question, though, so it doesn't strictly need a [mcve]. It would help if the OP showed an exact case, in which case we can objectively tell whether or not it is fully optimized away. At any rate, as it is right now, there are too many unknowns, so this question is too broad or unclear.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/NC2pa3 and https://godbolt.org/g/SrNWkp both have the same number of instructions in the compiled code.

Comment: @Justin, most compilers provide a switch for outputting the assembly language for a source file.  The OP should look at the compiler options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thanks to Jerry Coffin for the comment - my original answer was actually quite wrong...**

For this code:

```
struct TypeObject {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void print(int x);

void test(TypeObject *object) {
  print(object->a);
  print(object->b);
  print(object->c);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/SrNWkp produces something like this:

```
test(TypeObject*):
    push    rbx                     // save the rbx register
    mov     rbx, rdi                // copy the parameter (which is "object") to rbx
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx]    // copy inner->a to edi
    call    print(int)
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx+4]  // copy inner->b to edi
    call    print(int)
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx+8]  // copy inner->c to edi
    jmp     print(int)
    pop     rbx                     // restore rbx
```

And for this code:

```
struct InnerTypedObject {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct TypeObject {
    InnerTypedObject * inner;
};

void print(int x);

void test(TypeObject *object) {
  InnerTypedObject *inner = object->inner;
  print(inner->a);
  print(inner->b);
  print(inner->c);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/NC2pa3 produces something like this:

```
test(TypeObject*):
    push    rbx                     // save the rbx register
    mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi]    // copy "*object" (which is "inner") to rbx
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx]    // copy inner->a to edi
    call    print(int)
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx+4]  // copy inner->b to edi
    call    print(int)
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rbx+8]  // copy inner->c to edi
    jmp     print(int)
    pop     rbx                     // restore rbx
```

So the code is still dereferencing `object` - it stores the pointer once and then uses it three times just like the original code did.  The reason for not being able to optimize it better is that what is stored in a pointer is extremely hard to track so the optimizer has to assume it doesn't know what is in there for sure.

Even though both bits of assembly have the same number of instructions, there is an extra memory dereference in the one with "inner" so it could be expensive if the data isn't already in the cache.

Comment: This: `mov     rbx, rdi` (from the second sequence) is getting the value of the pointer that was passed as an argument. This: `mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi]` (from the first sequence) is getting what the pointer points at. So i't not eliminating `inner`, but it is loading the inner pointer in a register, then re-using it to access all the contents. So, it has the same number of instructions, but one extra memory access (which is potentially slow, if that location isn't in the cache).

Comment: I think this is orthogonal to what the OP is asking about, though. Here, you have to chase two pointers in one (notably one depends on the prior dereference, so it's a high chance of a cache miss), but only have to chase one pointer in the other. In other words, your answer is investigating whether an extra indirection through a pointer makes a difference. However, my reading of the OP is just asking whether it makes a difference to stash the temporary variable `InnerTypedObject* inner = outer->inner;` Not about whether it makes a difference to remove the layer of indirection

Comment: Interestingly, it does make a difference in this case: https://godbolt.org/g/EFFj2m . I believe this is because the `print` function could modify a global `TypeObject` which is passed in, which would make the code behave differently in both cases.